# magento 2.3.3 konckout translation doesn't work

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs, js-translation

Hello I have the official stripe module for magento 2 which is not trasnlated correctly.
This is the piece of code:

```
    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Use a new card'--><!-- /ko --></span>
```

I created the csv file into the i18n directory but the text is not translated.
I take a look into the js-translation.json file and the string it is not there.
If I manually put the string into that file it is translated. It seem that the process to insert the string into that file doesn't work.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @RakeshDonga Any other solution for this. issue below is not working for me??

Comment: @111 this is working for us you need to below commands for that

Answer (score 0):

try this following way..

In extension also provide default language `en_US.csv` file
[image]

And after run below commands

```
rm -rf var/di/* generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush
```